# How to get sikuli-script.jar for Mac

Tags: selenium, sikuli, sikuli-x

I want to integrate sikuli with selenium.Can anyone tell how to get sikuli-script jar for mac pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate sikuli with selenium, we need to follow the below steps.

- First Install Java in MacOS
- Download sikuli from https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download
- Double-click on “sikulixsetup-1.1.1.jar” to do 
  [image]
- Open Eclipse IDE and create a project